# SyntaxError: invalid property id - MongoDB and BASH

Tags: javascript, mongodb, bash

I have db-survey and collection-details.
On the terminal when I write-

```
(echo "use survey"; echo "db.details.find({age:10})") | mongo > age_ten.txt
```

It gives information of people whose age is 10 in age_ten.txt file.

But when I write-

```
(echo "use survey"; echo "db.details.find({age:{$gt:60}})") | mongo > medical.txt
```

It creates the file medical.txt but it has the error -

```
[js] SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell):1:22
```

Funnily when I write - `db.details.find({age:{$gt:60}}`  in mongo enviornment.It gives me the result that I want.

Can someone please explain me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone please explain me what I am doing wrong?

The `$` in the MongoDB *greater than* operator is interpreted by `bash` and the operator consumed. You can see this if you
`echo "db.details.find({age:{$gt:60}})"`

To prevent this, use `'` rather than `"`.